# SQL Server Grouping on consecutive values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2014 table which contains service records for a given supplier. I need to group by the Supplier_ID and consecutive ServiceDay values and output the min(CostingService_ID).

[Data and schema as SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/144599/1)

Here's the raw SQL data sample

```
CostingService_ID   Supplier_ID ServiceDay
722250  6191    1
722251  6759    2
722252  6363    3
722253  6903    4
722254  6301    5
722255  6301    6
722256  7667    7
722257  7195    8
722258  6191    10
722259  6191    11
722260  6191    12
722261  6191    13
722262  7195    9
```

So in this case I would like to output

```
722250  
722251  
722252  
722253  
722254  
722256  
722257  
722258
```

A normal group-by doesn't work in this case.

Comment: To clarify - 722259,722260,722261 should be excluded from the result as the  SetviceDay 11,12,13 are consecutive to ServiceDay 10 and has the same Supplier_ID.

722262  Should also be excluded, as its ServiceDay 9 is consectutive to ServiceDay 8 and they have the same Supplier_ID.

Comment: And if you had record with day 12 missing (722260), then you want to see next record (722261, day 13), because 11 and 13 are not consecutive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SELECT MIN(CostingService_ID) FROM (
  SELECT CostingService_ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ServiceDay) -
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Supplier_ID ORDER BY ServiceDay) grp
  FROM CostingService
) a GROUP BY grp
```

You need to use difference between row numbers to check if particular numbers are consecutive.

Comment: Sorry but this is a false success, it only works because non consecutive days for the same supplierID scenario is not present in the sample data

Comment: @DanielBrughera I doubt it :)

Comment: Change the second last record from (722261,  6191,    13) to (722261,  6191,    14)  to create the scenario, and you will get the same result, I already tested it

Comment: @DanielBrughera Why would you insert duplicated in `ID` column? Anyway, the resultset shouldn't change with this data and it won't.

Comment: I said change, not add, and it should change since 12 and 14 are not consecutive days, you should get two different values for that supplier id

Comment: I've tested with my data and Michal's query produces the expected result in all cases. One test was to change my Supplier_ID in row 722260 (day 12) and it correctly grouped day 10 and 11, had 12 on it's own, and then 13. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
  select CostingService_ID from (   
     select CostingService_ID ,  row_number() over(partition by Supplier_ID order by ServiceDay) rn from t
  ) t
  where rn = 1
  order by CostingService_ID
```

Comment: This produced exactly what I needed!. Thank you for intuiting what I was looking for despite my rather poor explanation

Comment: @Istari - Nice if that helped You

Answer (score 1):

This following script should give you MIN CostingService_ID per Supplier_ID

```
SELECT MIN(CostingService_ID)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Supplier_ID
```

Comment: Sorry I edited the data to illustrate better. The problem with this is is that I do want to see the CostingService_ID for the non-consecutive  occurences of the supplier. In this case 722250

Answer (score 0):

Use the row_number() function

```
SELECT CostingService_ID
FROM (SELECT CostingService_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Supplier_ID ORBER BY CostingService_ID) AS rownum FROM CostingService) AS a
where rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you need sometihing like

```
select *
from CostingService cs
where not exists(
    select * from CostingService
    where Supplier_ID = cs.Supplier_ID and ServiceDay = cs.ServiceDay - 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this approach, I tested adding non consecutive days for the same suppier and it works..

```
;with consecutives as (
    select Supplier_ID , ServiceDay
    from @t t1
    where not exists (select 1 from @t where Supplier_ID  = t1.Supplier_ID  and ServiceDay = t1.ServiceDay -1)
)
select t1.Supplier_ID , t1.ServiceDay, t2.ServiceDay as nextServiceDay, CostingService_ID
from consecutives t1
outer apply (
    select top 1 n.ServiceDay from consecutives n where n.Supplier_ID  = t1.Supplier_ID  and n.ServiceDay > t1.ServiceDay order by n.ServiceDay
) t2
outer apply (
    select min(CostingService_ID) CostingService_ID from @t where Supplier_ID  = t1.Supplier_ID  and ServiceDay between t1.ServiceDay and isnull(t2.ServiceDay - 1, t1.ServiceDay)
) t3
```